# Dependencies in Perl code

Tags: perl

I've been assigned to pick up a webapplication written in some old Perl Legacy code, get it working on our server to later extend it. The code was written 10 years ago by a solitary self-taught developer...

The code has weird stuff going on - they are not afraid to `do lib-param.pl` on line one, and later in the file `do /lib-pl/lib-param.pl` - which is offcourse a different file.

Including `a.pl` with methods `b()` and `c()` and later including `d.pl` with methods `c()` and `e()` seems to be quite popular too... Packages appear to be unknown, so you'll just find &c() somewhere in the code later.

Interesting questions:

- Is there a tool that can draw relations between perl-files? Show a list of files used by each other file?
- The same for MySQL databases and tables? Can it show which schema's/tables are used by which files?
- Is there an IDE that knows which c() is called - the one in a.pl or the one in d.pl?
- How would you start to try to understand the code?

I'm inclined to go through each file and refactor it, but am not allowed to do that - only the *strict minimum* to get the code working. (But since the code never `uses strict`, I don't know if I'm gonna...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not using strict is a mistake -- don't continue it. Move the stuff in `d.pl` to `D.pm` (or perhaps a better name alltogether), and if the code is procedural use `Sub::Exporter` to get those subs back into the calling package. `strict` is lexical, you can turn it on for just one package. Such as your new `package D;`. To find out which code is being called, use Devel::SimpleTrace.

```
perl -MDevel::SimpleTrace ./foo.pl
```

Now any warnings will be accompanied by a full back-log -- sprinkle warnings around the code and run it.

I think the MySQL question should be removed, from this. Schema Table mappings have nothing to do with perl, it seems an out of place distraction on this question.

Comment: Thanks - the Devel:: thingie seems to have some interesting stuff that might help me. I will `use strict` in my code, I'm just not sure if I will obey the "strict" in "refactor only the strict minimum" ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would write a utility to scan a complete list of all `sub`s and which file they live in; then I would write a utility to give me a list of all function calls and which file they come from.

By the way - it is not terribly hard to write a fairly mindless static analysis tool to generate a call graph.

For many cases, in well-written code, that will be enough to help me out...

Comment: There is already code that will do that. If you have the `subref` use nothingmuch's [Devel::Sub::Which](http://search.cpan.org/~nuffin/Devel-Sub-Which-0.05/lib/Devel/Sub/Which.pm)

Comment: @Evan: That documentation contains *far* too much unsaid for me to use that. Also, I am not fond of dynamic analysis, since it leaves out unrun paths.